# Install Mysql on Mac OSx with Python connector

Tags: php, python, mysql, macos

I am trying to install mysql onto my mac OS X 10.11.4. 
I have downloaded the mysql DMG from 
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

I have also downloaded the python connector dmg from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/

I have ran and installed both but I cannot tell if it was successful.

In python when I use the code:

```
import mysql.connector
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named mysql.connector
```

In terminal I have tried

```
type -a mysql
```

which returns:

```
-bash: type: mysql: not found
```

Have I missed a step?

Edit:

I have tried the code from:
https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/start-stop-mysql-from-the-command-line-terminal-osx-linux/
To start and stop mysql, which did not throw any errors, so I can assume mysql is installed and working.

Just need to get the mysql.connector to work?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by first installing pip (not sure what it is but it solved the issue)

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

Then typing this command to re-install python-connector:

```
sudo pip install mysql-connector-repackaged
```

Now everything is working :)

Comment: I suggest using _homebrew_ to install things like mysql and other mac packages. It is quite nice. Although if you already use MacPorts or Fink then it is recommended to remove them first (which can be a pain).